# Yahoo L3dsr loadbalancer install issue.why I have private key issue?

Tags: iptables, load-balancing, ip-routing

I need to make a load balancer. But I have to use l3dsr metod because my loadbalancer server and real server are in different locations and subnets.
I does configuration on my load balancer server and it is ok.
But in my real server centos 7 when I want to make iptables libs from l3dsr github it gives me error of invalid privte key.
So any body knows what is wrong?[this is my console picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsEW1.jpg)

And this are my commands :

```
yum install iptables-services kernel-devel iptables-devel gcc make git
systemctl enable iptables.service systemctl start iptables.service git clone
git clone https://github.com/yahoo/l3dsr.git
cd ~/l3dsr/linux/iptables-daddr/
make
make libdir=/usr/lib64 install
```